# numpy, scipy, interp1d - TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am doing interp1 using scipy.

```
N = 200

gam = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 50, 49, 49, 48, 48, 47, 47, 46, 46, 45, 45, 44, 44, 43, 43, 42, 42, 41, 41, 40, 40, 39, 39, 38, 38, 37, 37, 36, 36, 35, 35, 34, 34, 33, 33, 32, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 25, 24, 24]

np.array(gam)

# x is numpy array

x = [[ 0.005  0.01   0.015  0.02   0.025  0.03   0.035  0.04   0.045  0.05
   0.055  0.06   0.065  0.07   0.075  0.08   0.085  0.09   0.095  0.1
   0.105  0.11   0.115  0.12   0.125  0.13   0.135  0.14   0.145  0.15
   0.155  0.16   0.165  0.17   0.175  0.18   0.185  0.19   0.195  0.2
   0.205  0.21   0.215  0.22   0.225  0.23   0.235  0.24   0.245  0.25
   0.255  0.26   0.265  0.27   0.275  0.28   0.285  0.29   0.295  0.3
   0.305  0.31   0.315  0.32   0.325  0.33   0.335  0.34   0.345  0.35
   0.355  0.36   0.365  0.37   0.375  0.38   0.385  0.39   0.395  0.4
   0.405  0.41   0.415  0.42   0.425  0.43   0.435  0.44   0.445  0.45
   0.455  0.46   0.465  0.47   0.475  0.48   0.485  0.49   0.495  0.5
   0.505  0.51   0.515  0.52   0.525  0.53   0.535  0.54   0.545  0.55
   0.555  0.56   0.565  0.57   0.575  0.58   0.585  0.59   0.595  0.6
   0.605  0.61   0.615  0.62   0.625  0.63   0.635  0.64   0.645  0.65
   0.655  0.66   0.665  0.67   0.675  0.68   0.685  0.69   0.695  0.7
   0.705  0.71   0.715  0.72   0.725  0.73   0.735  0.74   0.745  0.75
   0.755  0.76   0.765  0.77   0.775  0.78   0.785  0.79   0.795  0.8
   0.805  0.81   0.815  0.82   0.825  0.83   0.835  0.84   0.845  0.85
   0.855  0.86   0.865  0.87   0.875  0.88   0.885  0.89   0.895  0.9
   0.905  0.91   0.915  0.92   0.925  0.93   0.935  0.94   0.945  0.95
   0.955  0.96   0.965  0.97   0.975  0.98   0.985  0.99   0.995  1.   ]
```

I am doing

```
sp.interpolate.interp1d(gam, x, x, 'linear')
```

I am getting error :

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

how to solve this? what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the arguments to [`interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) in the wrong order: `kind` (e.g. `'linear'`) should be the third argument, the fourth is `axis`, which should be an integer.

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what you want to happen, but probably just `interp1d(gam, x, 'linear')`.

Comment: solved that. thanks but then I got scipy object. how I will get the values from that object? I mean numpy array or list?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to: "This class returns a function whose call method uses interpolation to find the value of new points." There are usage examples at the bottom of the page.